# How to prevent saving unusual HTML entities from PHP form?

Tags: php

Every now and then, I get unusual data saved to the database from my PHP form that looks like this:

```
Mr. Smith&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;#039;s
```

What could be causing this, and is there a better way to remove the entities than using `preg_replace`, since the php decode functions don't properly decode the entire thing?

Comment: This seems like a bug in your form validation/input sanitization library. What are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This must be due to some technical problem. The best way to decode the entities and after that if you find something like:

```
/&([a-z]+|#[0-9]+);/
```

Do not accept the form, just alert the user about the invalid value.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the code processing data from the form pre-insertion into the database. If you are sanitising the data to be displayed on a web page use `htmlentities($var);` if you are are only sanitising it for security purposes look into [prepared statements / stored procedures](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or just `mysql_real_escape_string($var)`. If all else fails post the code and we'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at Codeingiters' source code where they remove entities at https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/src/c07dcadf094e/system/libraries/Security.php in the **xss_clean** method. This will give you a good idea of how to clean most of them more effectively.